# Class Item gets empty when List.Clear() using c#

Tags: c#

This is my class declaration:

```
    List<Carton> Cartons = new List<Carton>();
    public class Carton
    {
        public string CartonLabel;
        public string PN;
        public List<string> Serials;            
    }
```

This is a generic list that I will use at the end to assign it to Carton.Serials

```
    List<string> Serials = new List<string>();
```

Why Carton.Serials become empty when I do: `Serials.Clear()`

```
    if (Serials.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Carton CartonItem = new Carton();
                            CartonItem.CartonLabel = CartonData;
                            CartonItem.PN = PNData;
                            CartonItem.Serials = Serials;
                            Cartons.Add(CartonItem);
                            Serials.Clear();
                        }
```

Comment: Why the downvotes??? try to explain instead, I'm not asking crazy things here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You assign `Serials` to `CartonItem.Serials`. That doesn't create a copy. It's still the same list, both variables point to the same instance.

If you want to create a copy, you can call `ToList()`:

```
CartonItem.Serials = Serials.ToList();
```

Make sure you add `using System.Linq;` to the top of your *.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Clear()` removes all items from a generic `List<T>` which points to the same instance.

Comment: @Somebody: No, they are not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16362245/572644).

Comment: @Somebody, perhaps you should retract your statement.

Comment: I didn't know that, like me could be others and this will help them.

Answer (score 1):

it's indeed correct. `clear()` removes items from the list [Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dwb5h52a.aspx) MSDN Says. Refrences to other objects from elements of the collection are also released.

> Count is set to 0, and references to other objects from elements of
>   the collection are also released. Capacity remains unchanged. To reset
>   the capacity of the List, call the TrimExcess method or set the
>   Capacity property directly. Decreasing the capacity reallocates memory
>   and copies all the elements in the List. Trimming an empty List
>   sets the capacity of the List to the default capacity. This method
>   is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

Answer (score 1):

because when you say CartonItem.Serials = Serials; its sharing same object.

if you want to persist the values, then iterate through Serials and add each value to CartonItem.Serials

Answer (score 0):

`CartonItem.Serials` is a reference to `Serial`! So if you clear one, you (seem to) clear the other because it's the same instance (and not another).
BTW, the distinction between reference and value types is one of the most basic things in C#...